# Flash Builder 4.5 - orange question mark circle, how to get rid of it?

Tags: flash-builder

I noticed a new addition in the FB 4.5, a question mark in orange circle appears on the left border of text editor. I don't know what it should indicate but for my 4.1 project it appears on every single line of code with messages like this:

- Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: **String**

**Whaaa??**

I have no errors in the code and project compiles normally. Any idea how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **remove the yellow question mark from Flash Builder** *(especially when developing in Flash Professional from Flash Builder)*

1) Right click the right most area where all Markers appear, and select **Preferences**

[image: 1- Right click the right most area where all Markers appear]

2) In the Preferences panel, click on **Live Error Highlighting** and uncheck where you want it to appear.
[image: Preferences panel - Live Error Highlighting]

Answer (score 3):

The question mark in orange only appears when I open a Flash Professional-Project inside of Flash Builder 4.5 ;-( 
Code-Hinting as well as automatic imports are not working. Cleaning the project does not help.

If anybody wants to reproduce this error he can try the slideshow project code from the offical adobe devnet page:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_project_panel.html

The problem is also descriped in the adobe forum:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/864992

**Edit:**

I finally found a solution.
Locate the .actionScriptProperties File inside your Projectfolder. Inside the compiler-tag make sure the libraryPath is set correcty:

```
<libraryPath defaultLinkType="0">
  <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG}/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.2/playerglobal.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
  <libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="${FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG}/ActionScript 3.0/libs"/>
  <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG}/ActionScript 3.0/libs/11.0/textLayout.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
  <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG}/ActionScript 3.0/AIR2.6/airglobal.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
</libraryPath>
```

The yellow questionmarks should now disappear and you'll get codecompletion again. I posted a little more detailed explanation on the adobe forum link above.

;-)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by going Project > Properties > Actionscript Build Path. Remove the Flex 4.5 sdk library, click on Add Flex SDK. This will add the required sdk (in this case 4.5). Click ok, and this should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This may b due to imported classes are not registered properly, just import the classes/components again and clean your project by click on project menu and select clean. compile it and then see, if the same situation then reply here.

Comment: It doesn't even find the imports, yet it compiles them perfectly :) I have exactly the same SDK 4.5 and other project settings for this project as well as for newly created project inside FB 4.5 which works fine AND finds imports.

Comment: more specifically, it doesn't find the flash.* and mx.* package.

Comment: let me find another way to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me. Flash Builder > Windows > Preferences > Flash Builder > Editors > Uncheck "Report problems as you type"

This should solve the issue.

Comment: This might be because of the real time error checking. If unchecked it works for me. Also, FB is much more faster than before.